os.path.join is acting weird when I try to use placeholder format. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?
data_path = '/Users/acer/Downloads/t-less_v2/'
info_path_mask = os.path.join(data_path, 'test_{}','{:02d}','info.yml')
path_mask = os.path.join(data_path, 'test_{}','{}','info.yml')
print(f"info_path: {info_path_mask}")
print(f"path: {path_mask}")

I was trying to use placeholder in a script for accessing files located at multiple folder but I ran to error. I found the portion that was causing the error and when I tried to figure it out I found the os.path.join acting somewhat strange.
In the code I expected the output:
info_path: /Users/acer/Downloads/t-less_v2/test\_{}/{:02d}/info.yml

path: /Users/acer/Downloads/t-less_v2/test\_{}/{}/info.yml

But the output I got was:
info_path: {:02d}\\info.yml

path: /Users/acer/Downloads/t-less_v2/test\_{}\\{}\\info.yml


os.path.join() is doing exactly what it's supposed to – joining string components with path separators. What are you trying to do?

@AKX they are trying to join POSIX style paths in Windows, given Windows considers a colon to be a drive separator the {: is considered a drive name by os.path.join giving them an output they don't expect

@AKX I expected the output for the info_path to be /Users/acer/Downloads/t-less_v2/test_{}/{:02d}/info.yml to which I was later going to format the placeholder to look something like /Users/acer/Downloads/t-less_v2/test_canon/10/info.yml but the output I got is {:02d}\info.yml

@CivilEr Right – are you on Windows? If you are, what @AbdulAzizBarkat said holds true. (/Users/... smells like a macOS path though :) )

@ AKX yeah I am on windows and sadly I could not find any solution anywhere but I did worked around it. Thanks for all the comments and helps to you and to @AbdulAzizBarkat as well
